# How to call a function from one class into another(main) class in Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt

This is in reference to my previous post.

Present State: I have designed a keypad GUI in qt creator by making a separate class and i have displayed the entered text locally in that GUI. But I need to merge this keypad with my main GUI.

I have implemented'friend function concept' to achieve the task. But I m facing some errors in this

I m attaching the modified code along with the question:

**keypad class: .h file**

```
namespace Ui {
class kp16;
}

class MainWindow;

class kp16 :
        public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit kp16(QWidget *parent = 0);

    ~kp16();
     QString dat;
     void handles();

private:
    Ui::kp16 *ui;

   friend class Mainwindow ;  // Now mainwindow class   can access    private members of kp16
   **friend int MainWindow::inputdata( );**  // Inputdata() function of   mainwindow can access internal members of kp16

};
#endif //KP16_H
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

 public:
explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
**int inputdata( kp16 val );**  //declare inputdata function in  mainwindow
int i=0;


~MainWindow();
public slots:
```

**kp16.cpp**

```
kp16::kp16(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent),
ui(new Ui::kp16)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
connect(ui->k_pushButton_2,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(handles()));
}

kp16::~kp16()
{
delete ui;
}


void kp16::handles()
{
QPushButton* button = (QPushButton*)(sender());
QString fd=button->text();
dat.append(fd);
ui->label->setText(dat);
}
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
kp16 *kp;  //creating instance of kp16

int inputdata( kp16 val)     // friend function definition
{
 QString movedata=0;
 movedata=val.dat;
 return movedata.toInt();
}


void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_textEdited(const QString &arg1)     
{
    QString displayKeypad;
    displayKeypad= inputdata(*kp);

    ui->lineEdit->setText(displayKeypad);
}
```

ERRORS:

1. error: prototype for **'friend int MainWindow::inputdata()'**
   does not match any in class 'MainWindow'
   [in kp16.h]
2. error: **candidate is: int MainWindow::inputdata(kp16)**
   [In mainwindow.h]

Comment: For starters, `int inputdata(kp16)` should be `int kp16::inputdata()`.

Comment: Even if it is added to the class `inputdata( kp16 )` is not a valid function.

Comment: Did my solution work for your previous question?

Comment: No...because I have to make a touch screen keypad GUI. I am not  interfacing a hardware keypad/ keyboard to my system

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the error, `inputdata()` is not a *member* to class `kp16` it is *friend* to class `kp16`.

`->` (or `.`) operator can be used only with members. *friend* functions are used called as any other normal function.

To resolve your issue you just need to do following:

- Change the line `displayKeypad= kp->inputdata();` to `displayKeypad= inputdata(*kp);`
- Change the deceleration of `int inputdata( kp16 val );` function as `int inputdata( kp16& val );`
- Change the definition of `inputdata()` function as following:

  ```
  int inputdata( kp16& val)     // friend function definition
  {
   QString movedata=0;
   movedata=val.dat;
   return movedata;
  }
  ```
- Change `friend int MainWindow::inputdata( );` to `friend int MainWindow::inputdata(kp16& val);`. Though it is redundant because `MainWindow` is already friend to `kp16` class.

**Note:** Based on the way you are using *friend function*, I think you need to understand more about use of *friend* keyword. You can refer [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/friend-class-function-cpp/) to know more.

**Updated *(After question update)***:

As error log is sugesting, change line `friend int MainWindow::inputdata( );` to `friend int MainWindow::inputdata(kp16);`

Comment: Thanx for ur help..I have implemented the changes being suggested by u..and I have already gone through 'Geeks for Geeks' & 'tutorials point'...
But still some errors are coming....

Comment: Code :
Kp16.h:
private:
    Ui::kp16 *ui;

 friend class mainwindow ;  
// Now mainwindow class   can access private members of kp16
 
friend int MainWindow::inputdata( );
  // Inputdata() function of mainwindow can access internal members of kp16 declaring friend function

mainwindow.h

Comment: @ShubhamSInghRao Can you update the question to provide complete error log? As per above comment it seems that it is a warning not error. Also, can you confirm that in line `friend class mainwindow;` it is correct i.e. it should be `friend class MainWindow;` if I'm not wrong (See the _case-sensitiveness_).

Comment: I have updated the modified code with ur suggestions being implemented.  Plz go through it. Still it is indicating 2 errors.                                                                          And it is 'friend class MainWindow;' only .

Comment: @ShubhamSInghRao Answer is updated!!! Also, if it is `friend class MainWindow;` then update the same in your question. Though I can do this but I leave it upto you.

Comment: friend class MainWindow; Updated in the question too.

Any idea about errors?

Comment: By Implementing the aforesaid suggestions it is giving me new errors:

1. error: 'QWidget::QWidget(const QWidget&)' is private
     Q_DISABLE_COPY(QWidget)
     ^


2. In kp16.h:
     error:  within this context
     in class kp16 :
       ^